# Flutter Sfcalendar month view on web - how to change mouse cursors when it hover on cell

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar, sfcalendar

I tried MouseRegion over SfCalendar and in SfCalendar(monthCellBuilder itself) but it doesn't work. MouseRegion doesn't even detect mouse events. How can I change Cursors on the hovering month cell?
Thank you.

- (https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Lsi.png) - [not hover]
- (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZJTh.png) - [when hovering]

I tried MouseRegion has a child as SfCalendar.
**Result**: MouseRegion isn't detecting any mouse event.
**Expected**: Change cursors to SystemMouseCursors.click.

I tried MouseRegion in  SfCalendar>monthCellBuilder.
**Result**: MouseRegion is not detecting any mouse event.
**Expected**: To change cursors to SystemMouseCursors.click.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.